# Is there an opposite of a viewport in SDL2?

Tags: c++, rendering, viewport, sdl-2, alpha

I'm working on an alpha blending effect for which I need to be able to exclude a rectangular area of varying size and position on the screen from being rendered to, basically the opposite of a what a SDL_Viewport does. I can't use occlusion methods like SDL_RenderClear or SDL_RenderFillRect for this since that would interfere with the effect I'm going for, I actually need this area to only be rendered to once per frame.

Is there a better solution than having 4 constantly updated SDL_Rects acting as a frame of the exclusion zone to simulate something like a negative SDL_Viewport?

Comment: [`SDL_RenderSetClipRect()`](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_RenderSetClipRect)?

Comment: I already tried that, but unless there is something the wiki isn't telling me it doesn't seem to do anything. It just renders on the whole screen regardless of whether I have set a cliprect for my renderer or not. Are you guessing or do you know that's what it is supposed to do?

Comment: Guessing.  Looks like the behavior is the opposite of what I was expecting: you only get pixels *inside* the rect, not outside, sorry.

Comment: Yeah, I just got that to work too. It didn't work for me because I was using RenderClear, and that is not affected by the clipping. Anyways, thanks :)